# Travelling on/for business/work/tour/pleasure

Tags: prepositions

I'm travelling **on/for** business/work/tour/pleasure.

I don't know which preposition to use with business/work/tour/pleasure.

Comment: On tour. For pleasure. For work. On business, though you *might* say for business.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm guessing 'on tour' and 'on vacation' mean the same thing?

Comment: You're welcome! They *can* mean the same thing. People might spend their vacation touring around France, for example. But performers, bands, orchestras, theatre companies and others sometimes tour from city to city, performing - working - wherever they go. The context usually makes the meaning clear: "I'm on tour with my family", "I'm on tour with the London Symphony Orchestra" etc.

Comment: Thanks once again. Could you please tell me if there's a difference between travelling on business and for work?

Comment: It's mostly to do with one's pay! A plumber, someone *looking* for work, a lorry-driver and a piano-tuner *might* say they were travelling for work: never 'on business'. So might an astronaut. But *usually* they would say, "I'm a plumber" etc., or "I'm working". Only when travel is restricted (as under this Covid lockdown) might they explain to the police that they were travelling for work.

Comment: A businessman/woman, an arms-dealer, a hedge fund manager, an international fraudster and a politician would say they were travelling on business, as might anyone travelling for work but with an inflated sense of their own importance. (Estate agents spring to mind.)

Comment: Thank you very much once again.